# Initializing an empty ES6 class

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm building an app where I have a View which is a class which takes a bunch of properties to display, create, update, etc.

I setup my view like this

```
export default class {
   constructor(view) {
      this.id = view.id;
      this.title = view.title;
   }
}
```

I want to be able to initialize a `View` when a new view is being created, and I'm thinking the correct way is like this

`let newView = new View()`

Unfortunately, it appears if I do this, the constructor function is not called. When I run this test

`expect(newView.id).toBe(undefined)`

I get an error `cannot read property id of undefined`.

`let newView = new View({})`

Returns correctly, but I find it a bit odd to provide an empty object. Is this correct? Is there a better way to instantiate an empty class?

Comment: are you missing class name?

Comment: @AnubhavSrivastava No. It's a default exported class.

Comment: What do you mean 'empty class'? It has a constructor *which* expects arguments does it not? It can't find property `id` because you don't supply arguments to constructor, which assigns `id`. You could probably use the spread operator or provide a default argument.

Comment: `constructor(view = {})`? *"the constructor function is not called"* - I think it *is* called, but then crashes on `= view.id` because `view` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.

Your constructor is being called but it is defined with a parameter. In your first call you pass empty object:

```
let newView = new View();
```

Exception:

```
export default class {
   constructor(view) {   //view = 'undefined'
      this.id = view.id; //This line will cause exception.
      this.title = view.title;
   }
}
```

Therefore your parameter 'view' in constructor will be undefined and you will get your exception.

When you call:

```
let newView = new View({}); // new object {}
```

Your parameter 'view' will be defined and you can access its' props. (of course they will all be null)

Supplement:
Unfortunately there is no overloads on constructors, they still act like regular JS functions, there is a workaround you can do:

```
export default class {
   constructor(view) {  
      view = view || {}; //this is default value for param.
      this.id = view.id; 
      this.title = view.title;
   }
}
```

Then you are covered for new View() and new View({object})

Comment: Good point, but what I was trying to get at is that I expected something to be built in rather than having to define the object.

Comment: @pedalpete - Something *is* built in, specifically that if you don't pass a value the argument ends up `undefined`. That's not a *bad* thing, because it gives you a way to test whether the caller supplied a value or not. But ES6 lets you include default argument values, so that fixes your problem easily enough..

Comment: @pedalpete this still acts like a regular JS function, changing this now will cause so many errors on the web I think the world will collapse XD (see my edit for what you can do)

Comment: @ZivWeissman I had what you originally have in your supplement, but then went with a default variable of an empty object. No need to have the `view = view || {}` when you can have `constructor(view = {})`, right?

Comment: Yes, no need for both. @pedalpete

Answer (score 1):

You can use default parameters to set `view` object as a default variable identifier `view` with properties `id`, `title` set to `undefined`

```js
class View {
   constructor(view = {id: void 0, title: void 0}) {
      this.id = view.id; 
      this.title = view.title;
   }
}

var newView = new View();

console.assert(newView.id === undefined
              , {"message":"newView.id is not undefined"
              , "newView.id":newView.id}
);

console.assert(newView.id !== undefined
              , {"message":"newView.id is undefined"
              , "newView.id":newView.id}
);

console.dir(newView);
```

Comment: nice solution, but seems a bit verbose - I just changed to `view = {}` which is a bit cleaner, I was hoping something  was built in already.